# How to deploying c# windows application with database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, deployment, crystal-reports

I created a windows app in c# which uses a SQL Server database, and now I want to install it on a client machine. I already installed SQL Server 2008 on the client machine, now I created a setup and added all dll and exe files and also `app.config` file.

When I install it on client machine, I change the path in `app.config` from the program files of installation folder. But when I run the application it cannot connect to the database.

Please suggest some methods..to deploy this type of project with database and Crystal Reports.

Comment: if it can't connect to the database maybe the app.config still has the old (pointing to your development sql) connectionstring in it?

Comment: @Elger i update the app.config file but still not getting  it...

Comment: Check the user name and password in your client machine. also check which type of authentication is configured in SQL Server and what you are using in your web.config.

Try to connect client machine's sql server with client tool and configured credentials

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your authentication method to Windows authentication? Are you sure you are using app config in your dev environment?

Try to put a wrong password in your developement environment and see if it actually fails or not